# What is the alternative of crypto.subtle.exportKey in golang

Tags: go, cryptography, aes, aes-gcm

I'm trying to achieve the JS code below in golang, but I can't find any export key methods in crypto package of golang:

JS Code:

```
return Crypto.subtle.generateKey({
            name: 'AES-GCM',
            length: 256
        }, !0, ['encrypt', 'decrypt']).then(function(t) {
            const n = A.subtle.exportKey('raw', t);
            return n
        }).then(function(n) {
            console.log(n)
        }).catch(function(t) {
            throw t
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of `crypto.subtle.exportKey('raw', key)` is simply to use the `[]byte` value.

This is already the format for symmetric keys. eg: [aes](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/aes/#NewCipher) uses: `func NewCipher(key []byte) (cipher.Block, error)`.

So generating a key for AES256 and printing its raw value would be something along the lines of the following ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/euQtw5s-yV_C)):

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"  // Careful: do not use "math/rand".
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
  key := make([]byte, 32)  // 32 bytes for AES256.
  _, err := rand.Read(key) // read from random source
  if err != nil {
    // handle error
  }
  fmt.Println(key)
}
```

For other export formats and keys, you may want to look into [x509](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/), [pem](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/pem/) and per-algorithm key generation functions.

Comment: passing key as nonce argument to aesgcm.Seal gives "crypto/cipher: incorrect nonce length given to GCM", I'm not sure why

Comment: The `nonce` is **not** the `key`. To use AES in GCM mode, you need call `cipher.NewGCM` and pass it a AES cipher created using `aes.NewCipher(key)`. See the [example for AES GCM encrypt](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#example_NewGCM_encrypt)